# How can I use option "--bare" in Rails 3.1 for CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Someone know how can I use this option in Rails 3.1?
Now CoffeScript puts a function with `.call(this)` on each file, but I want to remove this.

EDIT:
"[Can't find variable” error with Rails 3.1 and Coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089992/cant-find-variable-error-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript)" and "[Pattern for CoffeeScript modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/5212449#5212449)" have what I want. I'll change my global vars to use `@global` scope.

Comment: Pretty much depends on what gem you use for CoffeeScript compiling.

Comment: `gem 'coffee-script'` standard in Rails 3.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd recommend against doing this. See my answer at [Pattern for CoffeeScript modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/5212449#5212449) for some of the reasons why. ("Making your CoffeeScript code incompatible with out-of-the-box Rails 3.1" is yet another reason.) Better to just use

```
window.a = b
```

or even

```
@a = b
```

instead of `a = b` when you're trying to export something to global scope.

In previous versions of Rails 3.1, `bare` compilation was enabled. This was [classified as a bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1125), and fixed in RC1.

So while I **strongly encourage you not to do this**, here's how to turn bare compilation back on: Add

```
Tilt::CoffeeScriptTemplate.default_bare = true
```

to your `environment.rb`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Im starting a new project, so I want to begin from the right way, I'll follow your strategy. Thanks :)

Comment: I agree if you have only some coffeescript files, but if you use a coffeescript file for each class/object you make you don't want to define a global variable for each one. +1 anyway for the answer

Answer (score 4):

I do recommend taking advantage of CoffeeScript's closures and following a CommonJS module patter. But sometimes, just sometimes, it is OK to want to use the --bare option. In my case, when rendering a Jasmine spec helper so I could keep things at the top level and also take advantage of the include Sprockets directive in said Jasmine specs.

To that end, I created the "sprockets-blackcoffee" gem, which you can learn about here. https://github.com/metaskills/sprockets-blackcoffee

Comment: I now realize that everything depends on the point of view and the kind of project. As in your case, I agree. :)

Comment: Very nifty. Your stuff has been cropping up a lot in the last few days, as I use minitest and CoffeeScript in Rails 3.2... Cheers! :-)