# Is there a CoffeeScript wrapper function to load all the files together?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

My CoffeeScript code is ~6,000 lines. For my sanity, I want to separate it to several files.

CoffeScript adds a wrapper for every file:

```
(function() {

  something = [1,2,3]

}).call(this);
```

But instead, I want it to wrap all the files in the manifest together. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the Sprockets `require` directive inside of your CoffeeScript file to require the code from another file.

```
#= require path/to/other/file
```

Otherwise you could also configure Sprockets to compile your CoffeeScript using the bare option, but it's not recommended.

See "[How can I use option “--bare” in Rails 3.1 for CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099342/how-can-i-use-option-bare-in-rails-3-1-for-coffeescript)" for more information.

Comment: This is so awesome. Where is it documented?

Comment: Now that I think of it, the docs don't specifically mention you can use the `require` directive inside of CoffeeScript. I actually picked up the tip at a Meetup. https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets

Comment: Well, it does work (if it's right on the top of the file) so thank you!