# How to not encapsulate Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, encapsulation

I don't know whether all coffeescript compilers wrap their scripts in anonymous functions, but that's what I see Rails doing. How can I disable this encapsulation?

I want to put several initializing functions in a single coffeescript file, then call one of them from an on-page `<script>` tag (so that each page calls a different initializer). This can't be if the initializing functions are encapsulated.

*Coffeescript initializer functions:*

```
initializerA = -> console.log 'foo'
initializerB = -> console.log 'bar'
```

*On-page code:*

```
<script>$(document).ready(initializerA)</script>
```

*Sys: coffee-rails 3.2.1, Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.9.3*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use option "--bare" in Rails 3.1 for CoffeeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099342/how-can-i-use-option-bare-in-rails-3-1-for-coffeescript)

Comment: @TrevorBurnham, similar indeed. However, I couldn't find that question, using search terms pertinent to this question and its answers, so this one must have some value.

Comment: That's the reason why duplicates are closed rather than being deleted: It allows them to point the way to a more canonical question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coffeescript documentation says that all script will be wrapped in an anonymous function for the sake of encapsulation/safety. To make something accessible within the global scope do the following:

```
window.myvar = myvar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put several into a single file by doing something like this:

```
((Demo, $, undefined_) ->
  Demo.utils = Demo.utils or {}

  Demo.utils.bacon = (->
      alert("bacon called")
    )()

  Demo.utils.eggs = (->
      alert("eggs called")
    )()
) window.Demo = window.Demo or {}, jQuery
```

Then in your page just call the appropriate method:

```
Demo.utils.bacon();
```

A good explanation of this pattern can be [found here.](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)

Comment: +1 for the detail. (The other guy's was a bit easier for me to digest.)