# Why my coffeescript function is not executed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am very new to this so I'm trying to follow the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html  and the  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html  Rails Guides
(I'm using Rails 4)

So in views/myController I have

```
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#990000')">Paint it red</a>
```

In app/assets/javascripts/myController.js.coffee the paintIt function

```
paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
   element.style.color = textColor
```

In app/assets/javascripts/application.js I have the directive:

```
//= require_tree .
```

so the coffeescript in myController.js.coffee should be compiled

And in views/layouts/application I have the

```
javascript_include_tag "application"
```

I also checked that the coffee-rails gem is in the gemfile and installed.

However in my view I see the "Paint it red" link but the coffeescript function is not triggered. (nothing happens)

Also checked that if I write the javascript inline it does work

WHy is this? What am I missing?

Comment: coffeescript wraps the code written in each file with a closure to avoid variables from shadowing and polluting the global scope. Try adding a `@` before paintIt so it will become a property of window: `@paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->`

Comment: I tried that  (although I didn't quite understand what it means) but It didn't seem to work

Comment: Try $(element).css("background-color", backgroundColor);

Comment: The code you write in myController.js.coffee will be executed inside a function where `this` refers to `window`(`@` is just a shortcut for `this`). Try keeping `@paintIt` and changing onclick to `window.paintIt(this, '#990000')`

Comment: Hey, thanks @PabloB.  I have now `@paintIt`  and `onclick=window.paintIt(this, '#990000')`, but I'm afraid that didn't do the trick either. Is there a way I can actually check that the coffee is compiling to javascript and  that I can access it ? ( Btw, I see the application.js is included as <script > in the html)

Comment: In the outputted HTML, check where you put `javascript_include_tag` and there should be a `<script>` for each CS file linking to the compiled version where you could see the javascript generated. BTW, add `console.log 'HELLO'` at the beginning of `paintIt` and check the console output to make sure it isn't getting called

Comment: Thanks again, I could finally get the function executed. I used `@paintIt` in myController.js.coffee and `onclick=window.paintIt` . But what did the trick was to specifically include the directive `//= require myController` in assets/javascripts/application.js . Don't know why but `//= require_tree .` did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, coffee-script uses with a top-level function wrapper. If you compile your file manually you can use the `--bare` command line option.

Else I will point you to the following post: [How can I use option "--bare" in Rails 3.1 for CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099342/how-can-i-use-option-bare-in-rails-3-1-for-coffeescript)