# Rails and CoffeeScript compile error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

Somehow in development environment my coffeeScript files compile correctly. But when I compile them for production I get something like this

CoffeeScript:

```
$->
  alert "hello world"
```

Compiled to Javascript

```
(function() {
   $(function(){
      alert("hello world");
   })
}).call(this)
```

I have checked for miss indentations and spacing errors, or for a mix of tabs and spaces but there are not any. The weird thing is that when I converted the with the compiler from coffeescript.org it compiles correctly, its just in the production environment. Any ideas?

by the way: I am using rails 4

Comment: It's a setting, the (function()... is a closure to avoid declaring global variables. It's ok and you should keep it anyway.

Comment: ["Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident."](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope)

Comment: That's exactly the correct compiled output, and it's definitely not a "compile error".

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL actually in development its more like $(function() {return alert("hello world");}); The issue I have with this is that its not called when the document is loading.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL was correct. This is a feature not an error. What was actually going wrong was that the production server hadn't precompiled the assets. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a coffeescript setting.

```
(function() {
  # Code here
}).call(this)
```

Is a closure generated by coffeescript by default (can be disabled, but you shouldn't), used to **avoid global namespace pollution**.
It doesn't affect the script execution, your jQuery code will still be run once document is loaded.

**Important note**
The only issue you may find with that closure is that you actually have hard time declaring global variables. This can be solved in this way:

```
window.yourvar = 'something'
```

There is also a suggestion here on how you can disable it anyway: [How can I use option "--bare" in Rails 3.1 for CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099342/how-can-i-use-option-bare-in-rails-3-1-for-coffeescript)