# How can Coffescript access functions from other assets?

Tags: coffeescript

So I have two controllers, `hotels` and `videos`.  I want the `hotels.js.coffee` to be able to access functions created in `videos.js.coffee` but I get a "is not defined" error.

I'm new to CoffeeScript so any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: There have been several recent questions along these lines. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099342/how-can-i-use-option-bare-in-rails-3-1-for-coffeescript/6099872 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137733/how-do-you-limit-coffeescript-or-javascript-execution-to-a-particular-controlle

Answer (score 14):

CoffeeScript will compile your coffee to JS wrapped in a self-executing function with the scope of the window (function{}).call(this);

So in videos.js.coffee you can write something like:

```
    @getVideo: (id) ->
```

and the getVideo function will be bound to the window object.

Comment: When I try this in a similar situation, I get a javascript error: missing : after property id
[Break On This Error] this.hide_modal: function(modal_id) {

My Function:
`@hide_modal: (modal_id) ->
  animate_top = Number($('#' + modal_id).height() + 70)
  current_top = $('#' + modal_id).css('top')

  $('#' + modal_id).animate
    top: '-' + animate_top + 'px'
    500
    -> $(this).css({'top' : current_top, 'visibility': 'hidden'}); $('.reveal-modal-bg').fadeOut()`

Comment: Sorry: http://pastebin.com/z9jFwfXp

I've since moved on and used the same code, just replaced the @hide_modal with window.hide_modal

Answer (score 8):

CoffeScript runs inside an anonymous function, so declared funcitons in the same file, aren't exported as global functions.

Try something like this to declare global functions:

```
window.myFunction = ->
    //some code
```

Answer (score 3):

During compilation, CoffeeScript wraps your code in an anonymous function and applies it.  You have to export your public interface in the expected manner for your environment.

```
(exports || window).publicMethod = (foo, bar) -> foo + bar
```

You then require using `require()` in node.js and by referencing the `window` object in the browser.

There are other ways to do this in the browser.  Look into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use either the top-level window variable, or the exports object provide through CommonJS. Please note, you can also give access to complete controllers instead of just functions.

See the sections 'Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety' and '"text/coffeescript" Script Tags' at http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/.