# Functions In CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to convert a `function` from Javascript to CoffeeScript. This is the code:

```
function convert(num1, num2, num3) {
    return num1 + num2 * num3;
}
```

But how I can do that in CoffeeScript?

---

I'm trying to run the function from an HTML source like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../coffee/convert.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    convert(6, 3, 10);
</script>
```

But it won't work and I get an error saying: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: convert`

How to correct this?

Comment: The answers given are correct, but what you really should do instead is get the remaining JS out of your HTML and into an external JS or CoffeeScript file. JS doesn't belong in HTML.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to export the convert function to the global scope.
See [How can Coffescript access functions from other assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163019/how-can-coffescript-access-functions-from-other-assets/6163057)

```
window.convert = (num1, num2, num3) ->
  num1 + num2 * num3
```

Comment: This answer is spot-on. It must be emphasized that once attached to `window`, `window.convert` can be accessed from anywhere as just `convert`; but writing `convert =` creates a variable called `convert` with local `var` scope.

Comment: Nice lawnsea, just hit this one today while calling a function from javascript (mixed). I remembered the anonymous scope but forgot Trevor's suggestion to slap it on window to make it callable outside of coffeescript's space

Answer (score 33):

@lawnsea answer is great.

I just want to add some thoughts.

Instead of polluting the global namespace, I prefer to add just one variable to the `window` object.

```
window.App = {}
```

Then, you can have access to `App` globally and add all your stuff there. the function `convert` can now be expressed this way:

```
App.convert = convert = (a, b, c) -> a + b * c
```

Then, to call the function within the local scope

```
convert 1,2,3
```

And now globally

```
App.convert 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 17):

At the top level of your coffeescript file, **this** (aka **@**) should refer to **window**. So to attach it here, you could use the shorthand:

```
@convert = (num1, num2, num3) -> num1 + num2 * num3
```

Note that this pollutes the global namespace, though. The solution posted by **jm-** is more prudent. But you can replace

```
window.App = {}
```

with

```
@App = {}
```

The benefit of using **@** is that it refers to **global** in node.js, so you can use the same code to expose your functions in both browser and serverside environments.

Answer (score 5):

```
window.convert = (num1, num2, num3) ->
  num1 + num2 * num3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check these awesome slides just released today by godfoca http://www.slideshare.net/godfoca/lets-have-a-cup-of-coffeescript  Also, you can try code out through-the-web at http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

```
convert = (num1, num2, num3) ->
  num1 + num2 * num3
```

Comment: Think you have a stray space in there: '- >'

Answer (score 0):

```
convert = (num1, num2, num3) -> num1 + num2 * num3
```