# how should I include a coffeescript file on only one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Edit: a year later if I was going to do this again I'd do it with curl.js instead of Rails asset pipeline.

Related: [Best way to add page specific javascript in a Rails 3 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app)

I'm writing an app and using coffeescript to generate all of the js. That's why the related question doesn't do what I need.

I'd like to be able to put a coffeescript file in a subfolder of my assets directory and have that .coffee file only get served up on one page. The page is on a named route

`match 'myNotifications' => 'user#notifications'`

The most obvious thing to do was to put the .coffee file in `assets\javascripts\user\index.js.coffee`. But after reading the docs about assets I'm unclear.

I read this line (from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> You should put any JavaScript or CSS unique to a controller inside
>   their respective asset files, as these files can then be loaded just
>   for these controllers with lines such as <%= javascript_include_tag
>   params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller]
>   %>.

Ok cool, so I put the page specific js in `assets\javascripts\user.js.coffee`. Then I reloaded my home page, Ctrl F5. The user.js file is still being loaded on the homepage. Tested with `$ -> alert 'ready from users controller'`; seeing that alert when I load the homepage.

Does Rails have a way to have a per-page coffeescript file that will only be served up with that page? Am I reading the manual wrong? Is there a place in the assets folder that I can put .coffee files where they won't get loaded with every page?

**Update**: Looks like I might [have an answer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?view=asciicast):

> There are a couple of ways that we can get around this problem. We
>   could use require_directory instead of require_tree as this will only
>   load the files in the current directory and not in subdirectories. If
>   we want more control over the included files we can require them
>   separately instead of including the whole directory. Alternatively we
>   could move the JavaScript files that we want to be included on all
>   pages into a public subdirectory. We can then use require_tree
>   ./public to include just those files.

I'll give that a shot in the AM.

Comment: Since I had the same problem, I decided to gather some different solutions I ran across in one place and did a small write-up here: [page-specific-javascript-in-rails-3](http://éncoder.dk/blog/2012/02/page-specific-javascript-in-rails-3/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than only including the file on one page, you might want to just use logic that's conditional on the page markup. See [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6133366/66226). That way, your users don't have to make an additional `<script>` request for the particular page.

If there's a *lot* of logic specific to that page (say, 10K+ minified), then yes, split it out. As you suggested in the edit to your question: Rather than doing `require_tree .` at the root of your `javascripts` directory, instead create a sub-directory called `global` and change the top of `application.js` from

```
require_tree .
```

to

```
require_tree global
```

Then put your page-specific CoffeeScript file in the root `javascripts` directory, and point to it with a `javascript_include_tag` call in that page's template.

Comment: I'm starting to see the logic of one big js file. This post says that there is a significant loading hit to having many js and css files: http://www.rubyrobot.org/article/5-tips-for-faster-loading-web-sites

Comment: Right. As I say, the advantage of splitting it out is that if that specific page has a ton of JS, you don't want people to have to download that when they load your home page. A third alternative is to use an asynchronous JS loader so that people who come to your home page load the scripts they need first, then all the rest after the page has loaded, so they'll be cached when they visit your other pages.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2 and it asked me to list the require_tree directory as a relative path so I used "require_tree ./global" and I was all set.

Answer (score 22):

Here's the approach I use to make controller/view specific Coffee:

*application.html.haml:*

```
%body{ :data => { :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action]} }
```

*alt. application.html.erb*

```
<%= content_tag(:body, :data => { :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action] }) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

*application.js.coffee:*

```
$(document).ready ->
  load_javascript($("body").data('controller'),$("body").data('action'))

load_javascript = (controller,action) ->
  $.event.trigger "#{controller}.load"
  $.event.trigger "#{action}_#{controller}.load"
```

*users.js.coffee*

```
$(document).bind 'edit_users.load', (e,obj) =>
  # fire on edit users controller action

$(document).bind 'show_users.load', (e,obj) =>
  # fire on show users controller action

$(document).bind 'users.load', (e,obj) =>
  # fire on all users controller actions
```

*Sidenote:*

*This works great with PJAX as well as you can pass the controller/action names with the response header on PJAX requests and just fire these js functions based on that.*

**EDIT (2014/03/04):**
This solution still works when using *turbolinks.js*.

Comment: Nice technique. Somehow I prefer regular jQuery/JavaScript to coffee. too much abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

include javascript tag into your view template, like `show.html.haml`

```
- content_for :javascripts do
  = javascript_include_tag 'folder/coffee_file_name'
```