# Triggering Coffeescript Functions in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, haml

In some of our Rails views, we have javascript functions that load certain data asynchronously to populate the page. Our application.js file loads all javascript in the assets/javascripts folder.

Here is a bit that's in one of our haml views:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    fetch_all_facebook_invitees();
  });
```

If we put the fetch_all_facebook_invitees function definition in a coffeescript file, it's loaded on every page because they're included in all pages of the application:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

What's the best practice to loading javascript for a page? Only doing it selectively and not load the entire tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how should I include a coffeescript file on only one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284117/how-should-i-include-a-coffeescript-file-on-only-one-page)

Answer (score 5):

You could solve this by having "partial" coffee files that you render inline.

`../assets/javascripts/inline/facebook_invites.js.coffee`

Make sure all events inside the file is fired when the DOM is loaded

```
$ ->
  # do Facebook stuff
```

*facebook.haml:*

`= javascript_include_tag "inline/facebook_invites"`

---

Then there's also the approach that I use to make controller/view specific Coffee files:

*application.html.haml:*

```
%body{ :data => { :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action]} }
```

*application.js.coffee:*

```
$(document).ready ->
  load_javascript($("body").data('controller'),$("body").data('action'))

load_javascript = (controller,action) ->
  $.event.trigger "#{controller}.load"
  $.event.trigger "#{action}_#{controller}.load"
```

*facebook.js.coffee*

```
$(document).bind 'edit_facebook.load', (e,obj) =>
  # fire on edit facebook controller action

$(document).bind 'show_facebook.load', (e,obj) =>
  # fire on show facebook controller action

$(document).bind 'facebook.load', (e,obj) =>
  # fire on all facebook controller actions
```