# What's the best way to selectivly run javascript when using the rails asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

The rails asset pipeline has it's issues, but the benefits of concatenating all my JS, minifying it and serving it with far-future expires headers are hard to ignore.

Lots of the JS in my rails app is specific to a single action. For example, we have a complex page for staff to enter customer orders.

pre rails 3.1, I had the action-specific code in a distinct JS file that was only loaded when needed. Now all my JS is served all the time. What's the best way to only run the order-entry JS when it's needed?

Currently I'm checking for the order-entry DOM elements, but that means there'll be lots of unnecessary functions running on DOMready.

Here's a snippet of coffeespcript from the order-entry code, and this pattern is repeated in about 20 files. Is there a better way?

```
$ ->
  window.app.draft = new app.DraftOrder()

@module 'app', ->
  class @DraftOrder
    constructor: ->
      @items = $('table.draft-items tr')
      return if @items.size() == 0
      @initEvents()
      @move_first()
    initEvents: ->
      # foo
    otherMethod: ->
      # bar
```

Comment: after submitting this question I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133235/rails-3-1-rc1-javascript-and-asset-pipeline - probably makes mine a dupe

Answer (score 2):

I like to wrap my page-specific JS in a closure, and insert code in my application template that lets me selectively execute it.

so, my page-specific js for an "Events" controller might look like:

```
events = {
  onload: function() {
    // put any page-specific onload code here
  },
  someOtherRoutine: function() {
  }
}
```

in my application template (application.html.erb), I add:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.controller_name = <%= params[:controller] %>;
  window.action_name = <%= params[:action] %>;
<% end%>
```

then, in application.js (assuming you use jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  if(controller_name === 'events'){
    events.onload();
  }
  else if(controller_name === 'anothercontroller'){
    anothercontroller.onload();
  }

  // put any global onload functionality here...
});
```

This has the additional advantage of giving a sort of poor-man's namespacing to all of your page-specific JS.

There's probably a more idiomatic rails/javascript way to do this; I'm not primarily a JS programmer but I am learning to like the language quite a bit...

Answer (score 0):

It is including all of your javascript files only because you have this line in your `application.js` file:

```
//= require_tree .
```

If you take that out, it will only include the files that you specifically require.  If you specify the name of a folder (rather than `.`), then you can have a spot where you put files that you want to be 'auto-included'.  You can read more about this in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).  For example, your application.js file could look like this:

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require main
```

Then, you could have an order_entry.js file that just has the code you want in it. Of course, you link to these the same way you used to:

For `application.js`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

For your new `order_entry.js`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "order_entry" %>
```

Comment: thanks, but I want my application.js to include all my JS to reduce HTTP requests and improve caching