# calling javascript functions from html in rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

Using coffeescript, jQuery, and sprockets in rails 3.1 the coffeescript files are compiled in to blocks like:

```
(function() {
 var a;
 var b;
 var c;
 foo = function() { 
  alert("foo");
 }
 bar = function() {
  alert("bar");
 }

}).call(this);
```

This seems to move functions foo and bar out of global scope, so bar can be called by foo, but neither can be called from the html code.  When I try to call foo from a select onchange element, I get a "Can't find variable: foo".

The workaround right now is to move all globally available functions to .js files.  But what's the right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I do it the same as Dogbert, you might want to check this out for other options (including this one) http://vimeo.com/24391448

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer declaring a top level object (for namespacing), and attaching all the functions that I'll need access to, to it.

At the top of your file, add something like

```
window.App = window.App || {};
```

Then declare your functions

```
var foo = function() { ... };
var bar = function() { ... };
```

Lastly, export functions needed

```
window.App.foo = foo;
```

Somewhat related info - ["Can't find variable" error with Rails 3.1 and Coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089992/cant-find-variable-error-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript/6090251#6090251)