# Why the heck is Rails 3.1 / Sprockets 2 / CoffeeScript adding extra code?

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

Working with Rails 3.1 (rc5), and I'm noticing that any coffeescript file I include rails (or sprockets) is adding in initializing javascript at the top and bottom. In other words, a blank .js.coffee file gets outputted looking like this:

```
(function() {
}).call(this);
```

This is irritating because it screws up my javascript scope (unless I really don't know what I'm doing). I generally separate all of my javascript classes into separate files and I believe that having that function code wrapping my classes just puts them out of scope from one another. Or, atleast, I can't seem to access them as I am continually getting undefined errors.

Is there a way to override this? It seems like this file in sprockets has to do with adding this code:
https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/jst_processor.rb

I understand that wrapping everything in a function might seem like an added convenience as then nothing is ran until DOM is loaded, but as far as I can tell it just messes up my scope.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099342/how-can-i-use-option-bare-in-rails-3-1-for-coffeescript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you intending to put your objects into the global scope? I think CoffeeScript usually wraps code in anonymous functions so that it doesn't accidentally leak variables into the global scope. If there's not a way to turn it off, your best bet would probably be to specifically add anything you want to be in the global scope to the window object:

```
window.myGlobal = myGlobal;
```

It seems to be a javascript best practice these days to put code inside a function scope and be explicit about adding objects to the global scope, and it's something I usually see CoffeeScript do automatically.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to understand that now. I'm working on putting everything into a global scope, thanks.

Comment: These two questions are similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685292/calling-javascript-functions-from-html-in-rails-3-1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089992/cant-find-variable-error-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript/6090251#6090251

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to put everything into the global scope.  You want a module or module like system where you can namespace things so you don't colide with other libraries. Have a read of

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Easy-modules-with-coffeescript