# How to define a callback function with Coffeescript and Rails 3.1?

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my view I want:

```
:coffeescript
  Gmap('#canvas').getAddressBounds request.term
```

which is defined in maps.js.coffee as

```
Gmap = (mapId) ->
  getAddressBounds: (address) ->
    data = []
    $(mapId).gmap3
      action: 'getAddress'
      address: address
      callback: (results) ->
        return unless results
        data = $.map results, (item) ->
          bounds: item.geometry.bounds
    data
```

This doesn't work though. First, there's a scope issue.  The Gmap function is not visible to the script in the view.  If I add the code directly to the view, Gmap is visible, but data always returns as [].

Comment: The scope issue you describe has become the most common CoffeeScript question on StackOverflow; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089992/cant-find-variable-error-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript and several others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's going on is that you're treating asynchronous code as if it's synchronous. Some debug output might help you visualize this:

```
Gmap = (mapId) ->
  getAddressBounds: (address) ->
    data = []
    console.log '1: Calling gmap3'
    $(mapId).gmap3
      action: 'getAddress'
      address: address
      callback: (results) ->
        console.log '3: Callback called'
        return unless results
        data = $.map results, (item) ->
          bounds: item.geometry.bounds
    console.log '2: Returning data'
    data
```

When you pass a callback, it could get called at any time. If it were called during the `gmap3` function, then `data` would indeed be set before being returned. But the reason `gmap3` uses a callback to return its result, rather than just returning, is that the function is asynchronous—in particular, it calls the callback when the server responds to your query. The way that JavaScript does events, that means your callback is guaranteed *not* to be called until after all code has finished executing.

There's no way to wrap an asynchronous function in a synchronous one in JavaScript (or CoffeeScript); even running an infinite loop until your callback is called wouldn't work, because, again, the JS runtime doesn't handle events like server responses (or even user input events) until all code has finished executing. So all you can do is change your function, too, to use a callback:

```
Gmap = (mapId) ->
  getAddressBounds: (address, cb) ->
    $(mapId).gmap3
      action: 'getAddress'
      address: address
      callback: (results) ->
        return unless results
        cb $.map results, (item) ->
          bounds: item.geometry.bounds
```

Then call it like so:

```
 Gmap('#canvas').getAddressBounds request.term, (data) -> console.log data
```

I talk a little bit more about the JS event model in [my CoffeeScript book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript). Also, John Resig's [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) is a must-read. Asynchronicity takes some getting used to, but the benefits over multithreading are spectacular.

Answer (score 2):

change
    Gmap = ...
to
    window.Gmap = ....

will solve the problem. The reason is coffeescript wraps everything in an anonymous function. If you want a more feature full module system have a look here

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Easy-modules-with-coffeescript

Comment: This solves the scope issue, but not the problem with `[]` being returned.

Comment: You are right, I only saw the most obvious problem. Pity StackOverflow won't let the OP select two answers ;)