# ruby variable in javascript in rails function

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to change the colour of a row according to a rails database value. Also within the row is a form which is a drop down menu. On changing the selected value in the drop down form I update the changed value to the DB by a form submit and then call a javascript function to change the row colour using the new value through AJAX.

html.erb:

```
<%= f.select(:status, ["to call","didn't connect","confirmed","rejected"], {:selected => lead.status}, :onchange => %Q[$('#lead_form_#{lead.id}').submit();document.getElementById('lead_row_#{lead.id}').bgcolor=Application.getRowColour("#{lead.status}");]) %>
```

In the above code what is happening is that the #{lead.status} which is being passed to getRowColour is always the same i.e. the initial value of status when I first load the page. So how many ever times I change the status via the dropdown, the getRowColour("") does not change.

**source of the page:**

```
$('#lead_form_133').submit();document.getElementById('lead_row_133').bgcolor=Application.getRowColour("confirmed");
```

As can be seen the getRowColour() is taking a constant value and not re-evaluating it on every call. How can I send my lastest status param to this function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id of the `status` select-box is `status` consider using the following construction:

```
<%= f.select(:status, ["to call","didn't connect","confirmed","rejected"], 
             {:selected => lead.status} %>
```

Then add the `onchange` handler logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#status").change(function() {
        $('#lead_form_#{lead.id}').submit();
        $('#lead_row_#{lead.id}')
          .css('background-color', Application.getRowColour($("#status").val())
    }); 
</script>
```